# Handling Custom fields using Rally API

Tags: java, rally

Recently I got a few custom fields added to 'New Test Case Result'. The image of the new fields are attached.

I am using Rally API to update test case results and now I need to handle these custom fields too. (JAVA)

Could anyone please tell me how to handle these fields?

For now I am handling the 'New Test Case Result' fields like this.

```
newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Verdict", "Pass");
newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Date", "2016-06-30T18:00:00.000Z");
newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Notes", "Regression Run");
newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Build", "3.0.3");
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom fields start with a c_ prefix.  So probably something like this:

```
newTestCaseResult.addProperty("c_Environment", "Prod");
```

Remember you can always browse the object model in your subscription by going to the WSAPI docs.  Here you'll be able to see all your custom fields on each object type.

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice